# How to use a literal link with a hyperlink tag?

Tags: html, vb.net, hyperlink

I am using a hyperlink in my code to re-direct the user to an article. At the moment the link is hard coded with a standard `anchor` with a href.

I've created a condition in my `code behind` :

```
If MyLists.MyListId = 1 Then 
       MyLists.MyListRecommendation = "Largest Number of Businesses"
       MyLists.MyListSummary = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
       MyLists.MyListUrl = "/how-to-become-a-developer/"
END
```

At the moment I am attempting to use a literal link how i've been using previously and this is where I am getting stuck.

```
<a href="<asp:Literal ID="MyListUrl" runat="server" /> ">VIEW ARTICLE</a>
```

Currently, when clicking on the hyperlink text the page is not re-directed to any url. It is re-directed to `/=` I am trying to get the hyperlink to re-direct to my `MyListUrl`

Comment: If you are trying to set a Web Control as a url (as shows your code) you are in wrong way.

Comment: ok.... what way can I approach it? @G3nt_M3caj

Answer (score 1):

Since you using asp anyway why not use an `asp:HyperLink`?

In your .aspx file...

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyLink2" runat="server">View Article</asp:HyperLink>
```

I had to guess what your class might look like.

In your code behind...

```
Public Class Links
    Public Property MyListId As Integer
    Public Property MyListRecommendation As String 
    Public Property MyListSummary As String 
    Public Property MyListUrl As String 
End Class

    Dim MyLists As New Links()
    MyLists.MyListId = 1
    If MyLists.MyListId = 1 Then
        MyLists.MyListRecommendation = "Largest Number of Businesses"
        MyLists.MyListSummary = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
        MyLists.MyListUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com"
    End If
    MyLink2.NavigateUrl = MyLists.MyListUrl
```

To work directly with an anchor tag.

In the .aspx file...

```
<a id="Beans"  runat="server">View Another Article</a>
```

Then in code behind just replace the `.NavigateUrl` line with

```
Beans.HRef = MyLists.MyListUrl
```